# How to find a vector from a quadratic form?

Tags: vectors

I am trying to find a vector $x$ from the equation

**$x^T A x = b$** when I know the matrix $A$ and the value $b$ already. Could someone help, please, and explain how it works?

Thank you

Comment: It does not work. For instance, when $A$ is the identity, it's like someone calling you on the phone and telling you: "I'm $b$ kilometers from you, please come and pick me up". Good luck finding him.

Comment: $A$ is symmetric and hence daigonalizable with ortho-nomal basis $A = P^T DP$  let $y = Px \implies y^TDy = b.$  Which is much easier to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about $A$ and $b$, solutions for $x$ will not necessarily exist, and if they exist they are not necessarily unique.  For example, consider $A = I$.  For $b = 1$, all unit vectors are solutions;  for $b = 0$, only $x = 0$ is a solution;  and for $b = -1$, there are no solutions.